# Can you please identify this beetle? (Rajasthan)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]
I thought that it was dangerous and kept it under a polythene at my home, in Rajasthan.

Is this insect harmful, rare or common? If the pic is not clear, I would like to mention that it is green, six-legged and its body is separated in two from the neck.

Comment: This looks more like a true bug than a beetle, and may be a member of superfamily Pentatomoidea; the photo isn't as clear as I would like.  If I'm right as to group, species range in habit from predator to agricultural pest (and North American members of similar appearance are closer to the latter).

Comment: I agree. Not a beetle, but a Pentatomidae.

Comment: Not harmful to people but some species in the family are agricultural pests. Common name is "stink bug", named for the defensive scent it gives off when threatened.

Comment: I also agree. Looks like some species of stink bug (also called a shield bug) in the Pentatomidae family. As Karl said, these are often agricultural pests. Other than a fowl odor when crushed, these insects pose no direct danger to you.

Comment: @Karl I think you can make an answer out of your comments. There will probably be no need to ID that organism down to the genus level.